# When I run the jQuery command the element doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to modify the dom with jquery, but when I run the command, the dom element doesn't exist. Is it possible to wait for the other script to build the necessary html elements?

I tried with the 'live' function, but doesn't help.

```
jQuery(document).live('ready', function(){

        var pressTitle;

        jQuery('.press-page .soliloquy-item').each(function(){

        pressTitle = jQuery(this).children().attr('title');

        console.log(pressTitle);

        });

    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try starting your function with $(document).ready('ready',function(){
.......

Comment: @vgSefa: You mean `$(document).ready(function(){`, but I think that was the original code...

Comment: Anyways, it's pretty obsolete. "live" is deprecated method, one should use "on" instead, jQuery instead of $ is pretty strange way to write code, imo.

Comment: Also, pressTitle = jQuery(this).children().attr('title'); will return the value of attribute "title" in HTML tag, for "this" is the document. Are you sure this is the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: @VladislavQulin: The context (`this`) is the element, not the document. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/each/ (Besides, the global context is the window, not the document.)

Comment: @Guffa, yeah, you're right, i just followed the indents :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if you find any elements, and if you don't, wait for a while and try again:

```
function getTitle() {
  var pressTitle;
  var t = jQuery('.press-page .soliloquy-item');
  if (t.length) {
    t.each(function(){
      pressTitle = jQuery(this).children().attr('title');
      console.log(pressTitle);
    });
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(getTitle, 100);
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(getTitle);
```

Comment: thanks to Guffa, I think same too. But first make sure your jQuery is being accessed and working. do a simple alert test.